# redirecting get request to post request? using express

Tags: express, redirect

Is that possible to redirect from Get request to POST request using Express JS? I'm just redirecting from API merchant a get request and need to throw a data back that's why i need to use POST request to send it back.

```
router.get('/webhooks/success',(req, res) => {
res.redirect(307, '/webhooks/success')
})

router.post('/webhooks/success', async function(req, res){
try{
    
    var request = require('request');
    var buffer = Buffer.from('pk-7xvHjw43SOGNLpot677GfxoLasdasdaa44TOJkREVMo')
    var base = buffer.toString('base64');
    let auth = 'Basic ' + base
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'url',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':  JSON.stringify(auth)
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({    
        ......
      })
    };
    // req.setHeader(options)
    request(options, async function (error, response) { 
      if (response === null || response === undefined || error) throw createError(403, error)
        console.log('RESPONSEE', response)
        if (response.statusCode === 200) return res.redirect('/success');
        throw createError(500, error)
    });
}catch(e){
    error_logs(e, req)
    req.flash('error', e.message)
    res.redirect('back')
}
});
```

Comment: Your rationale is confusing.  A GET request can return data just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Just ended up by using another api post request

```
router.get('/webhooks/success',async (req, res) => {
try{
    var request = require('request');
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'url',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
    request(options, async function (error, response) { 
      if (response === null || response === undefined || error) throw createError(403, error)
        if (response.statusCode === 200) return res.redirect('/success');
        res.redirect('/buy_ticket')
    });
}catch(e){
    error_logs(e, req)
    req.flash('error', e.message)
    res.redirect('/buy_ticket')
}
})
```